# Hosting Windows Application MDI Parent Form in WPF Application

Tags: wpf, winforms, mdiparent

I am opening a Window Application Form in WPF Application in C#. The process is simple as follows:

1. Create Windows Application. Add a form with buttons and labels etc.
2. Create WPF Application and add reference of Windows Application in it.
3. Add Reference "WindowsFormIntegration".
4. Add Reference "System.Windows.Forms".
5. Open PageXML.cs and in the initialize component function Create a new instance of Web Form.
6. Add One stack panel.
7. Inside the stack panel, add one windowsformhost control.
8. Create the instance of the form we created in windows application.
9. Add the form as a child inside windowsformhost control.

Everything works fine!
BUT
I cannot load the Windows form which is MDI Parent.

Normal form is fine but MDI Parent cannot be loaded.

Need Help to load that!

Thanks in advance.